# Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component />

Tags: reactjs, router, routes

Tengo un error al momento de crear mis rutas en react, cuando las mando llamar con "element" me dice que las importaciones no se están usando y por lo tanto me salen advertencias

WARNING in src\Router.js
Line 3:8:  'animationStandby' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
Line 4:8:  'formsPayment' is defined but never used      no-unused-vars
Line 5:8:  'referencePayment' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Este es mi codigo:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import animationStandby from './app/components/animationStandby';
import formsPayment from './app/components/formsPayment';
import referencePayment from './app/components/referencePayment';


export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
            <Route path="/animationStandby" element={<animationStandby/>}/>
            <Route path="/formsPayment" element={<formsPayment/>}/>
            <Route path="/referencePayment" element={<referencePayment/>}/>
            </Routes>  
        </Router>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el **error está en que en react por regla deben estar tus componentes con la primera letra en Mayúscula para que lo pueda reconocer**, debes cambiar cada nombre de los componentes.

Aqui te muestro como deberia de quedar asi como una recomendacion para el componente de navegacion.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import AnimationStandby from './app/components/animationStandby';
import FormsPayment from './app/components/formsPayment';
import FeferencePayment from './app/components/referencePayment';


export default class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <BrowserRouter>
            
            <Navbar />{/* componente de navegacion debes importarlo para que este en todas las paginas*/}

            <Routes>
            <Route path='/AnimationStandby' element={<AnimationStandby/>}/>
            <Route path='/FormsPayment' element={<FormsPayment/>}/>
            <Route path='/FeferencePayment' element={<FeferencePayment/>}/>
            </Routes>  
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
}
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!